# Codificación de longitud de ejecución - Problema 13 de los 99 problemas de Scheme

Tags: algoritmos, programación-funcional, lisp, scheme

Cree este código para resolver el problema 13 que es el del enunciado de
**Run-length encoding of a list (direct solution)**.

El problema es el siguiente, tengo una lista con sublistas y tengo que contar
los elementos que estan en esas sublistas. Pero no me cuenta las últimas **4 e**
alguna solución o que está mal en mí código?

Este es mi código:

```
(define encode-d
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          (else (encoding lst 1)))))

(define encoding
  (lambda (lst k)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
          ((equal? (car lst) (cadr lst)) (encoding (cdr lst) (+ k 1)))
          ((= k 1) (cons (car lst) (encoding (cdr lst) 1)))
          (else (cons (cons k (list (car lst))) (encoding (cdr lst) 1))))))
```

La salida del programa actual es la siguiente:

```
> (encode-d '(a a a a b c c a a d e e e e)
((4 a) b (2 c) (2 a) d e)
```

Pero la salida real deberia ser:

```
((4 a) b (2 c) (2 a) d (4 e))
```

**Esto está programado en Scheme**

Comment: Bienvenido, puedes explicar un poco de que trata el ejercicio? Tambien sería bueno que pusieras la salida del programa como texto (y no imagen), y la salida que esperas obtener.

Comment: El problema es el siguiente, tengo una lista con sublistas tengo que contar los elementos que estan en esas sublistas, la salida es la siguiente:

Input -> (encode-d '(a a a a b c c a a d e e e e)

Ouput-> ((4 a) b (2 c) (2 a) d e), esta es mi salida actual

La salida real deberia ser  -> ((4 a) b (2 c) (2 a) d (4 e))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que al llegar al final de la lista, la función en vez de
devolver el par con la cantidad y la letra, solo devuelve la letra.

Esto ocurre porque las condiciones de `cond` son exclusivas, y como la parte
que devuelve el par con la cantidad y la letra están al final (en el else),
solo se llega a ella si la siguiente condición es falsa:

```
(null? (cdr lst))
```

Esta condición se cumple en el nivel más profundo en los llamados a `encoding`,
porque en ese punto `(cdr lst)` es `'()` y `null?` se evalua en `#t`, así que
la función devuelve `lst`.

Para solucionarlo, hay que poner una condición más en el `cond`. Esa condición
es que `(null? (cdr lst))` se evalue en `#t` y `k` (las apariciones de la
letra) sea mayor a 1. Para no repetir la parte final, defino una función
auxiliar `retlst` y la uso en ambos lados.

Este es el código final:

```
(define encode-d
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          (else (encoding lst 1)))))

(define retlst
  (lambda (lst k)
    (cons (cons k (list (car lst))) (encoding (cdr lst) 1))))

(define encoding
  (lambda (lst k)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((and (null? (cdr lst)) (> k 1)) (retlst lst k))
          ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
          ((equal? (car lst) (cadr lst)) (encoding (cdr lst) (+ k 1)))
          ((= k 1) (cons (car lst) (encoding (cdr lst) 1)))
          (else (retlst lst k)))))
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me funciono muy bien.